# Integration by parts $\int(x+y)e^{-x}dx$

Tags: integration

What I'm trying to solve: $\int(x+y)e^{-x}dx$

Here's my professor's approach:
$$u = x, du = e^{-x}$$
$$du = dx, dv = -e^{-x}$$
By doing parts: $(-xe^{-x}) - \int(-e^{-x})dx - ye^{-x} = (-xe^{-x}) -e^{-x} -ye^{-x}$.
But, I am not sure how he used only $x$ as $u$ sub, not including $+y$ from $(x+y)$.
I am not sure how $(x+y)$ is handled here. 
Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be your integral, so

\begin{align}
S = \int e^{-x}\left(x+y\right) \,\mathrm{d}x&= \int \frac{x}{e^x}\,\mathrm{d}x + y \int \frac{1}{e^x} \,\mathrm{d}x\\
\end{align}

Now let $u=x$, with $\mathrm{d}u=\mathrm{d}x$. Let $v=-e^{-x}$. Then $\mathrm{d}v = e^{-x} \,\mathrm{d}x$. This means we can write $S$ as

\begin{align}
S &= \int u \,\mathrm{d}v + y \int \mathrm{d}v \\
&= uv - \int v \,\mathrm{d}u + yv\\
&=-xe^{-x} - \int -e^{-x} \,\mathrm{d}x - ye^{-x}\\
&=-\left(\frac{x+y}{e^x}\right) + \int \frac{1}{e^x} \mathrm{d}x\\\\
&=\boxed{-\displaystyle\frac{x+y+1}{e^x}}
\end{align}

This is equivalent to the expression your professor derived.